# pygame.error: video system not initialized when trying to run examples

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame

I'm trying to learn how to use pygame, but I'm having issues with running it. I installed it with the instructions here https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted.

They tell you to install it with

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

and then to test it with

```
python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

I ran these commands in Ubuntu and pygame was successfully installed. However, when I try to run the example I get

```
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
Warning, no sound
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
 File "/home/Paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/examples/aliens.py", line 321, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
 File "/home/Paul/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/examples/aliens.py", line 188, in main
     bestdepth = pygame.display.mode_ok(SCREENRECT.size, winstyle, 32)
pygame.error: video system not initialized
```

*I'm using Ubuntu terminal on Windows subsystem for Linux from the microsoft store.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6

**Following these instructions fixed it. https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I used your commands in a fresh ubuntu installation and it works here. Are you using a normal terminal?

Comment: @nosklo I'm using Ubuntu terminal on Windows subsystem for Linux. Sorry for not specifying earlier. I edited the post

Comment: To run the linux version you need a real linux system, with a X11 server to display the window - I don't think that works with the windows subsystem. Another option is to use python for windows and install pygame in windows directly.

Answer (score 0):

To run the linux version you need a real linux system, with a X11 server to display the window - I don't think that works with the windows subsystem. Another option is to use python for windows and install pygame in windows directly

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to get it working on windows subsytem with the steps here. https://virtualizationreview.com/articles/2017/02/08/graphical-programs-on-windows-subsystem-on-linux.aspx Once you pointed out the problem, doing all this was easier than getting it to work on windows.

Comment: @Paul performance will be terrible though - no hardware acceleration and lots of overhead